# Sending images through socket OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to send Images from one android device to another. Images were taken using OpenCV. I used TCP server to send Mat to other device using ObjectOutputStream. But It always gives an Exception. Is Mat class Serializable?

So i tried to send the image by converting it to a byte array using `Mat.get(0,0,byteArray);` and in the receiving side `Mat.put(0,0,byteArray);`
But when i checked the values being sent and received i noticed that the range of the values are not in 0 to 255 but in the range of -128 to 127.

So reconstructing the image is not happening. I mean when i tried to update a JavaCameraView using the Mat received it just shows a black screen. No pictures coming. I think it's because of the value shifting due to byte array transformation.

Is there anyway that i can send image from one android device to another using sockets and reconstruct the image in the other device?

Comment: I guess your original data is serialized as Int bytes (0 -> 255) but when receiving, data is serialized as Float bytes (-1 -> 1)

Comment: I'm kind of new to programming. Can you explain.? How to fix this?

Comment: A byte array contains bytes. And bytes are not signed or unsigned. They have just 8 bits. I think you receive the bytes and bits as they are sent. Just display the values in hex notation and you wil see.

Comment: Further you are not showing us how you send and receive the bytes. So what do you expect us to say? What you want seems doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use the following function:

```
std::vector<uchar> serializeImage(Mat img)
{   
    std::vector<uchar> img_vector;

    for (int i = 0; i < img1.rows; ++i) {
        img_vector.insert(img_vector.end(), img.ptr<uchar>(i), img.ptr<uchar>(i) + img.cols);
    }

    return img_vector;
}
```